# Neo4j: Unable to retrieve routing information

Tags: python, docker, neo4j

I'm trying to run the following Git repository: https://github.com/tomasonjo/bitcoin-to-neo4jdash#readme. I follow through all the instructions to set up the project in NeoDash. However, I can't finally connect to the Neo4j instance listed in the instruction. Can someone try to run the repository in Docker and share with me if they can really run the repository? Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried? What happened you tried it? What error or output did it show you?

Comment: Note: do not use the git or github tags just because you cloned a Git repository from GitHub.

Comment: @Kaan I tried to run it in localhost:80 as the instruction said but the import folder (which contains main.py) keeps saying that it fails to establish a connection with Neo4j (hence the 'Unable to retrieve routing information'). I think the main.py file is having problems trying to connect to Neo4j with their code but am unsure about how to fix the code.